# Accessing the array with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array (name array) which is smarty assigned and I want to access the value of every element of an array. I know we need to use eval here, but not sure how to use it?

```
var loop = 'true' , text , i=0;
while(loop == 'true')
{
   text = ~$array[i] ;//ERROR :-(
   i++;
   if(text=='')
       loop = 'false';
}
```

Comment: can you explain yourself better? also eval is last thing you should use ever, I mean in general in javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i in $array){
    text = $array[i]; //No error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To access every value of an array, just use a `for` loop:

```
var i, text;
for( i=$array.length; i--; ) {
   text = $array[ i ];
   // do something with text
}
```